# /dev/rtc0 not enabled for wakeup events and Cannot write '0' to /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm

Tags: 13.04, power-management

I am having Ubuntu 13.04 desktop 64bit

When running `rtcwake -s 30` , I get following results:

```
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: open failed: /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/power/wakeup: No such file or directory
rtcwake: /dev/rtc0 not enabled for wakeup events
```

Running `fwts s3 --s3-quirks -a`, I get a similar answer in the log:

```
Cannot write '0' to /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

Running `sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` , I get the result:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm: Directory nonexistent
```

How this can be fixed ?

Or how to enable `/dev/rtc0`  ?

Answer (score 0):

on my ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) system `sudo rtcwake -s 30 -mode mem` works as desired (but i need to set mode to 'mem' (=suspend to ram) or 'disk' as the default mode of 'standby' is not supported on my system (acer laptop).

what hardware are you running your system on? does it have a rtc and can your system discover it (as a first step, check the output of `ls -l /dev/rtc?`)?

your output-line `rtcwake: open failed: /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/power/wakeup: No such file or directory`
might show a relevant part of the problem. on my system /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/power/wakeup is also not present (i don't get that error-msg) but a wakealarm-namedpipe is located in `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`. does such exist on yours?

if this is the case, try to directly write into it, e.g. through

`sudo sh -c ‘echo "+00-00-00 00:00:30" > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm'`

note that this command does not set your system into sleep but only schedules a wakeup-alarm, so you might need to put your system to standby/sleep yourself.

then, what does `cat /proc/driver/rtc` say (especially lines starting with alrm_time, alrm_date and alrm_pending)?

probably not an answer but i can't comment yet...

**EDIT:** oops, just realized this was asked in 2012, not 2013...